# Merge 2 Tables Data in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have 3 Data Table Claim, Part and Labor.

In this Claim is parent table and Part and Labor is mapping tables of Claim and they have Part and Labor has the ClaimId as a Foreign Key.

Claim has data like:

[image]

Part has data Like

[image]

Labor table has data Like

[image]

Target Output would be:

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve this in SQL server.

I have tried to solve with the Union/CTE but it did not gives the result as I want.

Comment: How should the labor match to the claim/part? In the labor table you specify for LaborId=5 that it should match on ClaimId=3, but in the output it is 'joined' to ClaimId=5. Can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: Labor and Part is the referenced to the Claim via Claim Id but no direct relation between Labor and Part. Updated the Output screen.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec78e/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same output (for your updated output screen) for this specific case. I don't know if any other data will work for you.

```
    SELECT TMP.ClaimId
      , CASE WHEN TMP.RowNum = 1 THEN TMP.Name ELSE NULL END AS ClaimName
      , CASE WHEN TMP.RowNum = 1 THEN TMP.Note ELSE NULL END AS Note
      , TMP.PartId
      , TMP.PartNumber
      , TMP.PartCost
      , JOIN_L.LaborId
      , JOIN_L.LaborCost
    FROM (
      SELECT C.ClaimId, C.Name, C.Note, P.PartId, P.PartNumber, P.PartCost
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.ClaimId ORDER BY P.PartId) AS RowNum
      FROM Claim AS C
      LEFT JOIN Part AS P ON C.ClaimId = P.ClaimId
    )AS TMP
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY L.ClaimId ORDER BY L.ClaimId) AS RowNum
      FROM Labor AS L
    ) AS JOIN_L ON (TMP.ClaimId = JOIN_L.ClaimId AND TMP.RowNum = JOIN_L.RowNum)
    ORDER BY TMP.ClaimId
```

Comment: Let me check it on real data. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you tried CTE here

```
   Select C.ClaimId,C.name,C.Note,P.PartId,P.PartNumber,P.PartCost,L.LabourId,L.LabourCost
   From Claim C
        Left Outer Join Part P On P.ClaimId = C.ClaimId
        Left Outer Join Labor L On L.ClaimId=C.ClaimId
```

Comment: You did not see my target Output screen. this is not return result what I exactly want.:)

Comment: @Vijjendra: Can you please put the sample data on a http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? so I can try

Comment: Added please check now.

Comment: @Vijjendra: Send me the link please?